# How to work with physical addresses as a network and how does DMA connect to it?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, dma

I am working on a network driver and am somewhat confused with the memory management.
On the TX path, i receive a skb, as the lower layer expects to get only physical addresses, I think I need to call *virt_to_phys* and send the return value to the lower layer. 
(Does it make sense?)

Now, I know there are the functions *dma_map_single* and *dma_unmap_single*. I am still not sure how they come to the picture here. So the lower layer wants to work with DMA... Does it mean that I need to run the above commands (in the appropriate time) before dispatching the packet to the lower layer?

I also not sure I understand the meaning of the description of dma_map_single

*Ensure that any data held in the cache is appropriately discarded or written back.*

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files DMA-API.txt and DMA-API-HOWTO.txt in the Documentation directory of the Linux sources document how to use these functions.

You can't use `virt_to_phys()` and the like to get DMA addresses. That worked a long time ago in simpler times. Linux supports a wide range of hardware architectures and buses and for many of those, the address space the devices see does not map 1:1 to the physical address space of the CPU. Then there are also IOMMUs that can change that mapping dynamically. All of this necessitates the use of the DMA API.

Answer (score 1):

Physical addresses are not necessarily the same as I/O bus addresses, so you must always use the `dma_map_` functions.

On many systems, DMA accesses go only to main memory, which would break if there were a copy of that memory's contents in the CPU cache.
On these systems, the `dma_` functions take the appropriate architecture-dependent action to ensure that such conflicts do not happen.